# Создание и инициализация безымянных объектов с++

Tags: c++, инициализация

у нас есть вот такой код:

```
vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

Здесь я создаю безымянный объект типа `vector` и сразу же инициализирую его, такой код прекрасно компилируется. Но если я делаю так:

```
int[3]{1, 2, 3};
```

Такой код выбивает ошибку. Не могли бы вы рассказать что тут происходит,  почему нельзя создать безымянный массив и сразу же инициализироваь его?

Comment: Прямо представил себе картину как код с разворота **выбивает ошибку** из компилятора, и компилятор падает весь такой избитый, но дух его всё ещё не сломлен.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Другие ответы вводят в заблуждение, С++ разрешает создавать безымянные массивы и сами по себе, и в качестве аргумента функции. Главное использовать корректный синтаксис:

```
using t_Nums = int [2];

void fun(t_Nums const & nums);

void test(void)
{
    t_Nums{34, 42}; // безымянный временный объект
    fun(t_Nums{1, 2}); // аргумент функции
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xY8M1v143

Стоит отметить, что на `t_Nums{34, 42};` компилятор справедливо кинет предупреждение, так как создание массива встроенных типов не будет иметь каких-то побочных эффектов и лишено смысла.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, а не могли бы вы рассказать почему так?

Comment: Мне кажется тут дело в `[2]`, который делает составной тип массива

Comment: Не могли бы вы указать, какая конкретно фраза моего ответа вводит в заблуждение?

Comment: @gbg Вторая часть, про ругань компилятора - совершенно не верна. Компилятор ругается на синтаксис, а против создания временных объектов массивов - ничего против не имеет.

Comment: @n1kzzz Я не помню, как это правильно называется, но да, всякие составные типы нельзя использовать для прямой инициализации, например `long int{3}` тоже не будет работать.

Comment: Благодарю вас, и еще вот что - вот такая запись: `(int[2]){1, 2};`, прекрасно скомпилируется и будет работать, видимо в нашем случает квадратные скобки образующие составной тип, компилятор путает с оператором индексации и из-за этого все ошибки:)

Comment: @n1kzzz Это https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal и не должно компилироваться в ISO C++.

Comment: Не совсем понял, а почему оно не должно компилироваться?

Comment: @n1kzzz Потому что в С++ такого синтаксиса нет. Оно может скомпилироваться только с использованием нестандартного расширения gcc.

Comment: Да, действительно Visual C++ такое не компилирует, а очень жаль :(

Answer (score 6):

В первом случае, объект создается и немедленно удаляется. Так как у него есть конструктор с побочными эффектами, это может иметь какой-то смысл (например, это может быть класс, который вываливает переданное в файл), поэтому компилятор это честно компилирует.

Про второй случай смотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1271908/177993) @user7860670

Answer (score 1):

Анонимный объект — это значение без имени. Поскольку имени нет, то и способа ссылаться на этот объект за пределами места, где он создан — тоже нет. Следовательно, анонимные объекты имеют область видимости выражения и они создаются, обрабатываются и уничтожаются в пределах одного выражения. Пример: `func(2 + 8)`, `return Employee("John")`, `MyObj obj = obj1 + obj2;`, `print(Dollars(7));`, `add(Dollars(7), Dollars(9)).getDollars()`.

Возможно ли создать анонимный массив? Да, возможно, например, с помощью `std::initializer_list`

Вопрос на засыпку, что не так:

```
string var1 = "hello, ";
string var2 = "world!";
const char* var3 = (var1 + var2).c_str();
```

Компилятор выдает предупреждени потому, что `(var1 + var2)` - временный объект. Значение этого выржения удаляеться сразу, т.к здесь область видимости выражения. А метод `c_str()` будет ссылаться на несущевствующий объект.